# Android intent to viber user profile screen

Tags: android, android-intent, viber

I have an android app and I want to show viber user profile screen from my app. For this I use the following code:

```
                val uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(userPhone))
                val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW")
                intent.setClassName("com.viber.voip", "com.viber.voip.WelcomeActivity")
                intent.data = uri
                startActivity(intent)
```

When `Viber` app is in background this code works fine, I see the profile screen of user with `userPhone`. But when `Viber` app is fully closed (it is not in recent applications) my code start only the main page of Viber, not the profile page. How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

this is C# version translate to java

this for contact number:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
Android.Net.Uri.Parse("viber://contact?number=contactnumber"));
 Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

this for public  account chat:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
 Android.Net.Uri.Parse("viber://pa?chatURI=publicaccounturi")); 
 Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

this for public account info page:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
 Android.Net.Uri.Parse("viber://pa/info?uri=publicaccounturi"));
 Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

This will work even if viber is not running